# Contour integration in the complex plane gone wrong

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

Considering a function of complex variable $z$:
$$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z}$$
and a contour integral:
$$\oint_C dz f(z)$$
such that the contour $C$ encircles the origin counterclockwise, it is clear from the residue theorem that the result of the integration is:
$$\oint_C dz f(z)=2\pi i ~\text{Res}_{z=0}[f(z)]=2\pi i$$
If we map the complex plane onto a punctured sphere, the contour $C$ can be continuously deformed to $C'$ such that it encircles the point at infinity clockwise. This suggests that there should be a residue at infinity which gives us the same result as the one at the origin. Performing the substitution:
$$z=\frac{1}{w}~~~,~~~dz=-\frac{dw}{w^2}$$
we get
$$-\oint_{C''}\frac{dw}{w^2}f\left(\frac{1}{w}\right)=-\oint_{C''}dw\frac{e^{1/w}}{w}$$
where $C''$ now is a small clockwise circle around the origin in $w$. However, instead of giving the same result as above, the residue seems to diverge in this case. Something even more strange happens if we consider:
$$\oint_{C'''}dz \frac{e^z}{z(z-1)}=2\pi i(-1+e)$$
and then make the same kind of substitution here:
$$-\oint_{C''''}dw \frac{e^{1/w}}{(1-w)}$$
where $C''''$ is now supposed to encircle the point $w=0$, but there isn't even a pole there! Evidently, something goes very wrong here. Please, point out my errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laurent series expansion of $e^{1/w}/w$ about $w=0$, using the Maclaurin series for $\exp$, is
$\dfrac{1}{w} + \dfrac{1}{1! w^2} + \dfrac{1}{2! w^3} + \ldots$
and the residue, obtained as usual from the $w^{-1}$ term, is $1$.

Similarly for your other integral: $w = 0$ is not a pole but an essential singularity, and using the Taylor expansion of $\exp$ you can get the 
residue at $w=0$.

Comment: This Maclaurin series even appears to be the same as Taylor series in this case. Thank you, this cleared the clog in my mind!

Comment: Actually, concerning the second example I am still not quite sure. I see that: $-\oint_{C}dw \frac{e^{1/w}}{(1-w)}=-\oint_{C}dw \left(\frac{1}{(1-w)}+\frac{1}{w(1-w)}+\frac{2}{w^2(1-w)}...\right)=2\pi i$ and somehow $-\oint_{C}dw \frac{e~e^{1/w-1}}{(1-w)}=-\oint_{C}dw \left(\frac{e}{(1-w)}+\frac{e}{w}+\frac{2(1-w)}{w^2}...\right)=2\pi i e$ and even  $-\oint_{C}dw \frac{e^2 e^{1/w-2}}{(1-w)}=2\pi ie^2$ , but i dont see how to get the correct residue $-1+e$. Any suggestion?

Comment: OK! Got it. Had to expand the $1/(1-w)$, too. Gosh, I am so slow some times. Anyhow, thank you so much!